# Defining a variable and then calling it (undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filter, setstate

I'm defining a const variable called filteredRecipes and I'm trying to use it to setState. The console is reporting that filteredRecipes is undefined,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: filteredRecipes is not defined
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
updateRecipeList () {
    const filteredRecipes = fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {

            json.results.filter(

                function (recipe) {
                    return (
                        this.state.currentRecipe === "" || recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                    )
                }.bind(this)

            );

        });

    this.setState({
        recipes: filteredRecipes
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because your `this.setState` is outside of the Promise, meaning that I will not wait for the Promise to finish before trying to execute that code. Which means that the variable will be undefined.

You can solve this by putting it inside the promise like so:

```
updateRecipeList() {
  const filteredRecipes = fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      json.results.filter(
        function(recipe) {
          return (
            this.state.currentRecipe === "" || recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          )
        }.bind(this)
      );
      this.setState({
        recipes: filteredRecipes
      });
    });


}
```

Comment: I mean this will probably do what OP wants, but why is `filteredRecipes` undefined in the original version? It should have the value of the (unresolved) Promise object returned by `fetch`

Comment: Also you never assign anything meaningful to "filteredRecipes" either so it will still be undefined where you use it.

Comment: Exactly. Until the fetch finishes it basically returns nothing, so the value of the variable will be undefined.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `fetch()` returns a Promise *immediately*, before it "finishes", you couldn't call chained `then()`s otherwise. It's the foundation of composable asynchronous code.

Comment: It's entirely possible it's valid for `then()` to return undefined, I'm not thoroughly familiar with the Promises spec, it just seems thoroughly odd.

Comment: You don't assign the result of `.filter` to any variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it at the end of the Promise-chain:

```
updateRecipeList() {
    return fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {

            // you also missed `return` here    
            return json.results.filter(

                function(recipe) {
                    return (
                        this.state.currentRecipe === "" || recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                    )
                }.bind(this)

            );

        })
        .then(filteredRecipes => {

            this.setState({
                recipes: filteredRecipes
            });

        });
}
```

I also refactored your code just a little bit, I hope you don't mind. :)

```
updateRecipeList() {
    return fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            if (this.state.currentRecipe !== "") {
                const currentRecipe = this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()
                const filteredRecipes = json.results.filter(recipe => (
                    recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().includes(currentRecipe)
                ));

                this.setState({ recipes: filteredRecipes });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({ recipes: json.results });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
updateRecipeList() {
  fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
       const result = json.results.filter(recipe => {
           return (
            this.state.currentRecipe === "" || recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          );
        }
       this.setState({ recipes: result });
   );
 });
}
```

This is because this thread is running async and you need for the promise to execute when you set your setState.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because fetch is async and here are the ways you can do that either by setting state in then portion:

```
updateRecipeList() {
const self = this;
fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
    const filteredRecipes = json.results.filter(recipe =>
        self.state.currentRecipe === "" ||  recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

   self.setState({ recipes: filteredRecipes });
});
```

}
or you can use ES7 async function for fetching the result :\

```
async updateRecipeList() {
  const res = await fetch('http://www.***.co.uk/rest/recipes.json');
  const recipies = await res.json();
  const filteredRecipes = recipies.results.filter(recipe =>
     this.state.currentRecipe === "" ||recipe.pagetitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.currentRecipe.toLowerCase()) !== -1

   this.setState({ recipes: filteredRecipes });
```

}